# Are there such things as cyclically presented (arrows-only) categories?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, definition

### Motivation:

Let $w$ be an element of the free group $F_n$ on the generators $\{x_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$. Define a function $\theta: F_n\to F_n$ by $x_i\mapsto x_{i+1}$ (and extend this to all elements of $F_n$), where the subscripts are taken modulo $n$. Consider the *cyclic group presentation*

$$\mathscr{P}_n(w):=\langle x_0, \dots , x_{n-1}\mid w, \theta(w), \dots , \theta^{n-1}(w)\rangle.$$

Then the group $\mathscr{G}_n(w)$ defined by $\mathscr{P}_n(w)$ is called a *cyclically presented group*.

Similarly, one can construct a cyclically presented semigroup.

### The Question:

> Are there such things as "cyclically presented (arrows-only) categories"?

### Thoughts:

It might be necessary to restrict ourselves to arrows-only categories to make sense of the analogue of the "shift" $\theta$ in the case of group presentations.

I think I understand the [definition of a presentation of a category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presentation+of+a+category+by+generators+and+relations):

> Let $G$ be a directed graph, and let $R$ be a function that assigns to each pair $a,b$ of objects of the free category $F(G)$ a binary relation $R_{a,b}$ on the hom-set $F(G)(a,b)$. The **category with generators $G$ and relations $R$** is the quotient category.  For a category $C$, an isomorphism $C\to F(G)/R$ is called a **presentation** of $C$.

This definition seems to require that the binary relations, which in groups define the relators of the presentation, need to be "in two generators only", for lack of a better way of putting it. That might prevent us from making sense of a "cyclically presented (arrows-only) category".

Based on what it says about (the definition of) quotient categories being "evil" (which I don't fully understand), perhaps a cyclically presented category would, too, be "evil".

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily the case that $x_n\mapsto x_{n+1}$ gives a well defined function on the relations. You need a condition that if $x_mx_n$ is defined then so is $x_{n+1}x_{m+1}$. Given that, there's no issue.

It's not at all the case that relations can involve only two generators. They can involve only two *words* in the generators, but that's also true for groups.

The problem of evil is not relevant here.

Comment: Thank you, @KevinCarlson. I took the liberty of moving the final sentence of this answer to a paragraph of its own. It's a separate issue from the paragraph it was in previously.